# Can't convert math expression to numbers in Lua

Tags: lua

```
> print(tonumber("2+2"))
nil
```

Doesn't seem to work. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot *convert* an expression to a number, but you can define an anonymous function with the expression, compile it with Lua, and produce a value, like this:

```
f = loadstring("return 2+2")
print(f()) -- Prints 4
```